# JMenu issue with Gnome's native look and feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I stumbled on a very odd problem while trying to set up a JMenuBar with the native look and feel of Gnome. Here is a screenshot:
http://img23.imageshack.us/i/issuel.png/

It has to say File there but it gets cut out.

http://pastebin.com/CjFhmxcf

http://pastebin.com/gwB3vnC3

Any, help is appreciated!

Comment: This problem is getting even more weird. I run the code on a Windows XP virtual machine and it showed perfect... so much for the write once/run everywhere :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are adding icon after the menu itself has been attached to the frame. You should do all menu operations before displaying it, or call

```
menuBar.validate();
menuBar.paint();
```

after all menu decorations are done.

I have something like this

```
JMenu mFoo = new JMenu("Foo");
mFoo.setIcon(new ImageIcon("icon.png"));
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
menuBar.add(mFoo);
setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

in my `JFrame` working perfectly, also with GTK look-and-feel.